# How to develop a pdf similar to calendar events grid using jasper. (width and height of each cell varies with duration of event)

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I need to develop a pdf report similar to calendar events grid using jasper. The width and height of each cell will be different and is dependent on duration of the event.

I tried using charts, cross tabs and subreports in jasper, but was not able to achieve the desired result.

Also, I found many similar questions posted in jaspersoft community but with no response.

Which feature in jasper can help me achieve this? Please refer the attached image for the required format.

[Required PDF format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw4Hh.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple.

1. group for weeks
2. in the detail band create a list containing all entries
3. set the print order of the list to horizontal

And that's it. I just created a little example using sample dates and grouping it by years:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.2.1  -->
<!-- 2016-12-05T12:30:51 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="calendar_format" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="780b0fc5-3da2-4049-b760-6576fc896a7b">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit." value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageHeight" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.pageWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.topMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.bottomMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.leftMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.rightMargin" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnWidth" value="pixel"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.columnSpacing" value="pixel"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="d9734fed-9b79-4dd6-8974-41abbe93e802">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <parameter name="Year" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select datum from sample_data
where lpad(datum, 2) =  $P{Year} 
order by datum]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="DATUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select datum from sample_data
order by datum]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DATUM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATUM}.substring( 0, 2 )]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="108" height="34" uuid="cdf54289-974e-4a87-ba92-930b1d9f9a67"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATUM}.substring( 0, 2 )]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="ca1258cf-3b53-4670-a526-2a57a79d20a2">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.CONTENTS.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Horizontal" ignoreWidth="true">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="50e04de8-2040-4bc0-8ce0-5cbda45fd0c6">
                        <datasetParameter name="Year">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATUM}.substring( 0, 2 )]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="50">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="50" height="30" uuid="cc78cfdd-e53d-44f0-9dc3-efe45bf7e8fa">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{DATUM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**But you will have problems with empty days. I see no good workaround for this problem.**